# How can I change the time when AWS RDS automated snapshots are taken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-backups

We have data ingests set to feed our prod AWS RDS Aurora database from 1am to 5am each day, and we re-create our stage database each day by restoring the latest prod automated snapshot.

Unfortunately, the prod automated snapshots currently occur at 12am, so the morning ingested data aren't yet in the snapshot, and we need the data to be there for the tests we run against the stage database upon deployment to prod.

Is there a way to change the timing of automated RDS snapshots, or do we just need to run a script that creates a manual snapshot to get our desired snapshot timing (i.e., after all needed data are in prod)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Automated snapshots' are snapshots that the Amazon RDS service takes to enable automated backups. These snapshots are taken within the *backup window* specified when first creating the database.

You will need to [modify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html#USER_ModifyInstance.Settings) the backup window specified, which can be done in a variety of ways:

- the console
- the [`modify-db-instance`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/modify-db-instance.html) CLI command
- [`ModifyDBInstance`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyDBInstance.html) RDS API operation (or equivalent SDK abstraction)

There is no need to create a script to create a manual snapshot in this case.